# Arrow Spinning in Canvas according to Cursor Position

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on a script which is supposed to do the following. You lock your mouse to a canvas. It will show you an "artificial" cursor instead that you can also move by using your mouse. Under this cursor, you will have a circle which also moves with the mouse.

All of this worked perfectly fine with my script which was until I added another nice feature: I want to have an Arrow in the middle of the canvas which stays there, exact same size, but rotates according to your cursor movement. To give you an idea what I'm talking about, I made these example graphs (don't worry about dimensions and colour).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/poO6n.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/twXhY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFFBe.jpg

I did some calculations to do this, implemented them, hoped for the best, but it doesn't work. I thought when it works, it will be a cool feature for everyone to have on this site. But so far I didn't see where my mistake is. If you have a clue, I'm absolutely grateful for every answer.

Many thanks!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>ArrowSpin</title>
          <style>
             html, body {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             }
             html {
             font-family: sans-serif;
             }
             canvas {
             display: block;
             margin: 0 auto;
             border: 1px solid black;
             }
             .information {
             width: 640px;
             margin: 0 auto 50px;
             }
             #tracker {
             position: absolute;
             top: 0;
             right: 10px;
             background-color: white;
             }
             h1 {
             font-size: 200%;
             }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="information">
          <img id="mousecursor" hidden="true" width="13" height="20.5" src="mousecursor.png" alt="Cursor">
          <p id="demo" style="color: black" oncl></p>
          <p id="Message" style="color: black" oncl></p>
          <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="360">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas
          </canvas>
          <div id="tracker"></div>
          </div>
          <script>
             try {
             
            // helper functions
             
             const RADIUS = 20;
            
            // this image is you mousecursor
             var img = document.getElementById("mousecursor");
             
            // degree to radians
             function degToRad(degrees) {
             var result = Math.PI / 180 * degrees;
             return result;
             }
             
            // generate a random number, later on, mouse cursor should start at random position, now unused     
             function generateRandomNumber() {
             var minangle = 0;
             var maxangle = 2*Math.PI;
             randangle = Math.random() * (maxangle- minangle) + minangle;
             return randangle;
             };
    
            //this function draws the actual arrow
                 
             function drawArrow(fromx, fromy, tox, toy, colourarrow){
                        //variables to be used when creating the arrow
                        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                        var headlen = 3;
                
                        var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);
                
                        //starting path of the arrow from the start square to the end square and drawing the stroke
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
                        ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = colourarrow;
                        ctx.lineWidth = 20;
                        ctx.stroke();
                
                        //starting a new path from the head of the arrow to one of the sides of the point
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(tox, toy);
                        ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));
                
                        //path from the side point of the arrow, to the other side point
                        ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/7));
                
                        //path from the side point back to the tip of the arrow, and then again to the opposite side point
                        ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
                        ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));
                
                        //draws the paths created above
                        ctx.strokeStyle = colourarrow;
                        ctx.lineWidth = 20;
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.fillStyle = colourarrow
                        ctx.fill();
                    }
             
             // this function calculates the current angle of the cursor from the exact middle of the canvas (x0,y0) by using two simple assumptions which are a) radius=sqrt(sqr(xfrom)+sqr(y)) b) x=x0+radius*cos(alpha) <=> alpha=arccos((x-x0)/radius)    
                 
             function CursorAngle() {
             var currentrad=Math.sqrt([Math.pow(x-canvas.width/2)+Math.pow(y+canvas.height)]);
             var currentangle=Math.acos([(x-canvas.width/2)/currentrad]);
             return currentangle
             }
                 //in this function I use the just calculated cursor angle to now calculate where my arrow shall begin and end, again I use x=x0+radius*cos(alpha) and y=y0+radius*sin(alpha). In this case I always want my arrow to have a radius of 50 and I always want it to be drawn in the center of the canvas.
                 
             function ProbeAngle(alpha) {
                 var x1 = canvas.width/2+50*cos(alpha)
                 var y1 = canvas.width/2+50*sin(alpha)
                 var x2 = canvas.width/2+50*cos(alpha+Math.PI)
                 var y2 = canvas.width/2+50*sin(alpha+Math.PI)
                 return [x1; y1; x2; y2]
             }
             
             // setup of the canvas
             
             var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
             var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
             
             var x = canvas.width/2;
             var y = canvas.height/2;
             
             //refresh the canvas
             
             function canvasDraw() {
             ctx.fillStyle = "black";
             ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
             ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.arc(x, y, RADIUS, 0, degToRad(360), true);
             ctx.fill();
             ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);         
             }
             canvasDraw();
             
             // pointer lock object forking for cross browser
             
             canvas.requestPointerLock = canvas.requestPointerLock ||
                                   canvas.mozRequestPointerLock;
             
             document.exitPointerLock = document.exitPointerLock ||
                                  document.mozExitPointerLock;
             
             canvas.onclick = function() {
             canvas.requestPointerLock();
             canvasDraw();
             };
             
             // pointer lock event listeners
             
             // Hook pointer lock state change events for different browsers
             document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);
             document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);
             
             function lockChangeAlert() {
             if (document.pointerLockElement === canvas ||
             document.mozPointerLockElement === canvas) {
             console.log('The pointer lock status is now locked');
             document.addEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition, false);
             } else {
             console.log('The pointer lock status is now unlocked');  
             document.removeEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition, false);
             }
             }
             
             //tracker shows x and y coordinates of "pseudo" cursor
             
             var tracker = document.getElementById('tracker');
             
                 //border protection for our image not to move out of the canvas
                 
             var animation;
             function updatePosition(e) {
             x += e.movementX;
             y += e.movementY;
             if (x > canvas.width) {
             x = canvas.width;
             }
             if (y > canvas.height) {
             y = canvas.height;
             }  
             if (x < 0) {
             x = 0;
             }
             if (y < 0) {
             y = 0;
             }
             tracker.textContent = "X position: " + x + ", Y position: " + y;
             
             if (!animation) {
             animation = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
             animation = null;
             canvasDraw();
    
    //receive the ProbeCoords by using the functions CursorAngle and ProbeAngle and draw it!
                 var ProbeCoord = ProbeAngle(CursorAngle());
               drawArrow(ProbeCoord[0],ProbeCoord[1],ProbeCoord[2],ProbeCoord[3],'white')
             });
             }
             }
             }
                         catch(err) {
                 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
                         }
                 document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "potential Errorcode above";
             
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Fabric JS?](http://fabricjs.com/manage-selection) In the linked example you can click an object and a handle appears at the top. After that you can click handle and it will follow the mouse. I'm suggesting this because most likely there is a way to change the click event to a hover event and then get the handle to follow the mouse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but my script already includes stuff following the mouse cursor likr the image and the circle. These work absolutely fine. It's just the spinning arrow that doesn't work